# Create sqlContext from a text file in spark using scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to create SQLContext using scala Below is m snippet of code.

```
object SqltextContextSparkScala {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    System.setProperty("hadoop.home.dir", "C:\\hadoop-2.6.0")
    val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("SampleSparkScalaApp").setMaster("local[2]").set("spark.executor.memory", "1g")

    val sc = new SparkContext(conf);
    val sqlContext = new SQLContext(sc);

    val readfile = sc.textFile("C:\\tmp\\people.txt")

    import sqlContext.implicits._

    val person = readfile.map(_.split(",")).map(p=> new Person(p(0), p(1), p(2)))
      sqlContext.to

  }

}
```

I have created on class of Person:

```
class Person(id:String,name:String,age:String){

}
```

How can i create dataframe here:

`val people = readfile.map(_.split(",")).map(p=> new Person(p(0), p(1), p(2))`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution ..The issue was with defining calss Person.

it was like below before:

```
class Person(id:String,name:String,age:String){

}
```

found that a **case** is requred before declaration  like below

```
case class Person(id:String,name:String,age:String){

}
```

but not sure what is the use of case here.

Answer (score 0):

Before:

```
val people=
```

Add a statement:

```
import textContext.implicits._
```

And after:

```
val people
```

Just do

```
val peopleDF = people.toDF()
```

And you are done.

Comment: No Sumit...I dont get implicits option their..I am using intellij not the spark window

Comment: John - Irrespective of IDE you should be able to import "textContext.implicits._" in scala. I have also modified my answer to use "textContext" instead of "sqlCtx"

Comment: what is the version of Spark are you using? "implicits" were introduced in Spark 1.3.0

Comment: 1.5.2 version..toDF fun is not available in my case

Comment: "toDF()" will be available only after you import "SQLContext.implicits._". can you please post the complete code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98692/discussion-between-sumit-and-john).